# Question involving ARMA Model

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, laplace-transform

So I've been doing a couple of these type of questions. However i am stuck on this one!

Consider the ARMA model
$$y(t + 2) + y(t + 1) −0.75y(t) = u(t + 1) + 4u(t)$$

Is it stable; is it invertible?

Convert this ARMA model to a state space model.

Find the general solution of this ARMA model in the case
$$u(t) = (−2)t$$
.
Find the particular solution corresponding to the initial conditions
$$\cases{y(0) = −1 \\ y(1) = 1}$$

So the bit im stuck on is when finding if it is stable on not its a fraction in the quadratic because is gives you $0(B)=1+B-0.75B^2$.

How do you solve this?

This is my answer for the first section I used the quadratic formula to solve $1+B-0.75B^2$. This gave me $-2/3$ and 2, because one of the modulus is smaller than 1 it isn't stable.

Then to find if it is invertible I used the second half of the ARMA model and got the 1-4B=0, thus $B=1/4$, showing it isnt invertible.

To convert it into a arma model is an easy part, however finding the general solution was not. Ive had a go and got $y(t)=A(1/2)^t+B(-3/2)^t+8/5(-2)^t$.

When using the inital conditions i got $y(t)=3/20(1/2)^t-11/4(-3/2)^t+8/5(-2)^t$ which really doesn't sound right! any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It's encouraged to learn LaTeX math typesetting (MathJax). Also to show any attempts you've made and to provide context to the problems if you think it would help getting response.